# UNNotificationAttachment is not working on iOS 14

Tags: ios, unnotificationserviceextension, unnotificationattachment

I implemented `UNNotificationServiceExtension` to attach image thumbnail on push notification. (By using `UNNotificationAttachment`).
It works really well on iOS 13. But after updating to iOS 14, it is not working though.

There is no thumbnail image on push notification, but if I do "force touch" action on notification, then image shows up. That means image is downloaded well in temp directory.

Also changing title, subtitle, and body are works well even on iOS 14, only except for `UNNotificationAttachment`.

Are there any changes on notification service extension?

## SOLVED

After rebooting device, it works very well..

Comment: I'm seeing this too

Comment: @KyleRedfearn After rebooting device, it works very well. 

Comment: I was able to fix mine by removing the options. The file type I was passing in was invalid